# Objectify - test if object exists using only the key?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I want to test if an object exists in the datastore. I know its key. I am doing this right now by loading the entire object:

```
public boolean doesObjectExist(String knownFooId) {

    Key<Foo> key = Key.create(Foo.class, knownFooId);

    Foo foo = ofy().load().key(key).now();
    if (foo != null) {
        // yes it exists.
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

That must cost 1 read operation from the datastore. Is there a way to do it without having to load the entire object, that might be cheaper? In other words, a way that it would only cost 1 "small" operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it cheaper.

Even if you just do a keys only query, the query is 1 Read operation + 1 Small operation per key fetched. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls)

Keep doing a get by key, which is just 1 Read.

Comment: Ok yeah the app engine documentation was a little ambiguous to me, I tried what @AndersonQ suggested (that's how I was interpreting their docs, too), but yeah reads still get incremented.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean doesObjectExist(String knownFooId) {

    Key<Foo> fooKey = Key.create(Foo.class, knownFooId);    
    Key<Foo> datastoreKey = ofy().load().type(Foo.class).filterKey(fooKey).keys().first().now();

    return datastoreKey.equals(fooKey);

}
```

From [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/6.0.2/com/googlecode/objectify/cmd/SimpleQuery.html):

> QueryKeys keys()
>   Switches to a keys-only query. Keys-only responses are billed as "minor datastore operations" which are faster and free compared to fetching whole entities.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fetch the key, as far as I understand it'd be only a small operation.

```
// You can query for just keys, which will return Key objects much more efficiently than fetching whole objects
Iterable<Key<F>> allKeys = ofy().load().type(Foo.class).filter("id", knownFooId).keys();
```

It should work. Also take a look at the objectfy docs: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries

Comment: Ok I wrote a test that uses this, and unfortunately the "Datastore Read Operations" quota does go up.